# How to get the username from Facebook in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I want to fetch the username of the user in username field into the parse.

I am using `loginWithFacebook(withcompletionHandler)` and `fetchUserInforFromFacebook(withcompletionHandler)` to fetch userinfo but I have a problem: These methods create an own object and store in parse username field, but I want to get the user username.

```
func loginWithFacebook(withcompletionHandler: (success:Bool) ->()){
    var permissions : Array = [ "user_location","public_profile"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {

                self.fetchUserInforFromFacebook(withcompletionHandler)

                println("User SIGNED UP and logged in through Facebook!")
                }
            withcompletionHandler(success: true)
            println("User logged in through Facebook!")

        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the FACEBOOK LOGIN.")
            self.showErrorMessage(error!)
            withcompletionHandler(success: false)
        }
    })
}
func fetchUserInforFromFacebook(withcompletionHandler: (success:Bool) ->()){
    if ((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){

        var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me", parameters:nil)
        request.startWithCompletionHandler({connection, result, error in
            if error == nil {

                //FACEBOOK DATA IN DICTIONARY
                var userData = result as NSDictionary
                var currentUser : PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()
                currentUser.setObject(userData.objectForKey("id") as String, forKey: "faceBookID")
                currentUser.setObject( userData.objectForKey("name") as String, forKey: "fullName")
                                currentUser.email = userData.objectForKey("email") as? String
                currentUser.username = userData.objectForKey("email") as? String






                var location = userData.objectForKey("location") as? NSDictionary
                var locName = location?.objectForKey("name") as? String
                if let loc =  locName {
                    var fullNameArr = split(loc) {$0 == ","}
                    var city: String? = fullNameArr.count > 0 ? fullNameArr[0] : nil
                    var contry: String? = fullNameArr.count > 1 ? fullNameArr[1]: nil

                    currentUser.setObject(userData.objectForKey("country"), forKey: "countryName")
                    currentUser.setObject(userData.objectForKey("city"), forKey: "cityName")

                }
                currentUser.saveInBackground()
                withcompletionHandler(success: true)

            }else{
                println("Error")
                self.showErrorMessage(error)
                withcompletionHandler(success: false)
            }
        })


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much easier approach to get the username:

**Firstly** *you need to call the FBSession method to get basic profile info and ID of the user.*

**Secondly** *Once we get user FB ID, we can directly pass the FB ID in graph API: `https://graph.facebook.com/?id=1008223822` aand get the username in the following json format:-*

```
{
   "id": "1008223822",
   "first_name": "Dj\u00e9",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "Destolicci",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/dje.destolicci",
   "locale": "fr_FR",
   "name": "Dj\u00e9 Destolicci",
   "username": "dje.destolicci"
}
```

---

**Here is code:-**

---

```
//first do simple login and authenticate user to get basic profile info and FB ID
FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"] , allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: { (session:FBSession!, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error==nil)
            {
                FBRequest.requestForMe().startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                    if (error==nil)
                    {

                        var bUserFacebookDict = result as! NSDictionary

                        let FB_USER_ID = bUserFacebookDict["id"]! as! String

                        // now call FB graph API to to Get username of the user.
                        var graphProfileURL = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/?id=\(FB_USER_ID)")


                        var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: graphProfileURL!)
                        var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?
                        >=nil
                        var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
                        var dataVal: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response, error:nil)!
                        var err: NSError
                        println(response)
                        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                        println("Synchronous\(jsonResult)")


                        let FB_USER_NAME = jsonResult["username"]! as! String //finally you will get username


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Utility.showErrorAlert(error.description)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: Why an additional block around `FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath...`?

Comment: @Vizllx Username was deprecated by Facebook in v2.0, but Im guessing that he means full name. basic_info has also been deprecated and replaced by public_profile.

Comment: the username stores in parse like that "xjgh4556hsjsjsjj" but i want to get the correct user name like "Rock" how we do for that?

Comment: @UsmanJaved- check my updated answer, it will return you the username.

Comment: @Vizllx - "use the undeclared type FBSession" this error is occure in this code

Comment: @UsmanJaved did you imported it in your Bridge-Header file, as you are doing it in swift?

Comment: how do I access the username outside this function though? Let's say I wanna display the username in the screen. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"] , allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: { (session:FBSession!, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error==nil)
                {
                    FBRequest.requestForMe().startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                        if (error==nil)
                        {
                            // get All Facebook data from user
                            //http://graph.facebook.com/67563683055/picture?type=square
                            //NSLog("%@",result as! NSDictionary)
                            var bUserFacebookDict = result as! NSDictionary

                            bstrFirstName = bUserFacebookDict.objectForKey("first_name") as! String
                            bstrLastName = bUserFacebookDict.objectForKey("last_name") as! String
                            bstrUserName = bUserFacebookDict.objectForKey("name") as! String

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Utility.showErrorAlert(error.description)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
```

Comment: OP is asking for username?None of the answer satisfies OP's question

Comment: i think name key is give's to your Username.